# JS code which will trigger multiple hover divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, triggers

I am new to JavaScript and I am trying to write a simple function that will trigger multiple div hovers. Until now I tried with many things but I assume this code will be closer to the solution. If someone could help me I would be really grateful.

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('mouseenter','.Test1', function() {
    if($('.Test2').hasClass('Test2')) {
       $('.Test2').toggleClass('Test2:Hover');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.Test1{
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#951159;
}

.Test1:Hover{
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#654654;
}

.Test2{
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#147852;
}

.Test2:Hover{
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#654654;
}
```

```html
<div class="Test1">1</div>
<div class="Test2">2</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

PS: I know that it could be done only with CSS but I need it with Javascript.

Comment: you can use jquery hover() method or javascript's onmouseover method to achieve it

Comment: why do you do `if($('.Test2').hasClass('Test2'))` as it's pointless! Tell us the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best to use CSS classes. and add and remove them by javascript.

```js
  $(function(){
  //reset box 
    $('.Test1').hover(function() {
        $('.Test2').addClass('hover');
    }, function(){
  $('.Test2').removeClass('hover');   
    });
  });
```

```css
.Test1{
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#951159;
}

.Test1:hover{
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#654654;
}

.Test2{
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#147852;
}

.Test2:hover, .Test2.hover{
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#654654;
}
```

```html
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<div class="Test1">1</div>
<div class="Test2">2</div>
```

Comment: If you can't add classes to the CSS file then you can add the css directly to the object with $('.Test2').css('background-color', '#654654'); and reset the color on the end hover function.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).on('mouseenter','.Test1', function() {
    if($('.Test2').hasClass('Test2')) {
       $('.Test2').trigger('mouseover');
}
});
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work, because the styles the OP is using are using the `:hover` pseudo-selector, which does not get triggered this way.